# Firestore - Append to tableView when view is loaded

Tags: swift, uitableview, append, google-cloud-firestore

Can someone please show me how I can append data from Firestore into an array? What I would like to do is make it so that when the view appears the data is appended into the below array and then into the correct labels of the tableView. When I call print("(document.data())") the data shows the way it should do in the bottom panel, I just don't know how to make it so that it appends into my array. Any help would be greatly appreciated, Many thanks!!

[Firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVnzI.png)

[Xcode bottom panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MvUC.png)

```
struct DetailsAdded {
    var titleName: String
    var detailsName: String

}

var array = [DetailsAdded]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    db = Firestore.firestore()
    loadData()

    }

func loadData() {
    db.collection("Users").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        } else {
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                print("\(document.data())")
            }
        }
    }

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CreateWorkoutCell", for: indexPath) as! CreateWorkoutTableViewCell

    cell.titleLabel.text = array[indexPath.row].titleName
    cell.detailsLabel.text = array[indexPath.row].detailsName

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    if let snapshot = querySnapshot {

        for document in snapshot.documents {

            let data = document.data()
            let name = data["name"] as? String ?? ""
            let details = data["details"] as? String ?? ""
            let newDetails = DetailsAdded(titleName: name, detailsName: details)
            array.append(newDetails)
        }

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: Works perfectly!! Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi sorry about all the questions! But how can I make it so that when I press add it creates a new autoID as a document and then passes that to a new view controller so that I can use the ID just created as a string? Many thanks once again!!

Comment: Hi.  If you're creating a new firestore document, you can just do this in your second `ViewController`.  You can create an auto ID with `let newID = UUID().uuidString`.  Then use that as your documentID and use `setData` to create your document.

Comment: The other way of doing it is just to call `.addDocument` instead of `setData`, and Firestore will create a UUID for you.  Depends whether you need to know what the UUID is beforehand or not.

Comment: Hi rbaldwin, would it be possible for you to have a look at my new question? I’d really appreciate your help again, thank you!