# Firestore- Showing data in Tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, google-cloud-firestore

I am attempting to show my Firestore data into my Tableview but I can't seem to get it to show up.

```
protocol DocumentSerializeable {
    init?(dictionary:[String:Any])
}

struct Sourse {
    var name: String
    var content: String
    var timeStamp: Date

    var dictionary: [String: Any] {
        return [
            "name": name,
            "content": content,
            "timestamp": timeStamp
        ]
    }
}


extension Sourse : DocumentSerializeable {
    init?(dictionary: [String : Any]) {
        guard let name = dictionary["name"] as? String,
            let content = dictionary["content"] as? String,
            let timeStamp = dictionary["timeStamp"] as? Date else {return nil}

        self.init(name: name, content: content, timeStamp: timeStamp)

    }
}

class SourseListTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var db: Firestore!

    var sourseArray = [Sourse]()

    private var document: [DocumentSnapshot] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self

        //initalize Database
        db = Firestore.firestore()
        loadData()

    }
```

At first I tried this code below, there were no errors but nothing loaded in the tableview.

```
func loadData() {
    db.collection("sourses").getDocuments() {
        snapshot, error in
        if let error = error {
            print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            self.sourseArray = snapshot!.documents.flatMap({Sourse(dictionary: $0.data())})
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After some research (reading from [Firestore - Append to tableView when view is loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50191787/firestore-append-to-tableview-when-view-is-loaded) )  I tried this code below, but I get the error "Cannot convert value of type '(name: String, content: String, timeStamp: Date?)' to expected argument type 'Sourse'" So I tried it with the date removed from all the code and I still couldn't get it to work.

```
func loadData() {
        db.collection("sourses").getDocuments() {
            snapshot, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                for document in snapshot!.documents {

                    let data = document.data()
                    let name = data["name"] as? String ?? ""
                    let content = data["content"] as? String ?? ""
                    let timeStamp = data["timeStamp"] as? Date 

                    let newSourse = (name:name, content:content, timeStamp: timeStamp)
                    self.sourseArray.append(newSourse)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is my numberOfRows/CellForRow to make sure its not the tableview itself. I've also double checked the "cell identifier" with my storyboard.

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return sourseArray.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SourseTableViewCell", for: indexPath)

        let sourse = sourseArray[indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(sourse.name)"
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(sourse.content)"

        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reload your `tableView` after parsing your `Snapshot`.  It is also not a good idea to force unwrap your `Snapshot`:

```
.getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in

    if let error = error {

        print(error.localizedDescription)

    } else {

        if let snapshot = snapshot {

            for document in snapshot.documents {

                let data = document.data()
                let name = data["name"] as? String ?? ""
                let content = data["content"] as? String ?? ""
                let timeStamp = data["timeStamp"] as? Date ?? Date()
                let newSourse = Sourse(name:name, content:content, timeStamp: timeStamp)
                self.sourseArray.append(newSourse)
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! I have been working on this problem the past few days. Much appreciated!!

I implemented the "reload data" with no issues.

But when I remove the force unwrap from snapshot I get the error "Value of optional type 'QuerySnapshot?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?"

Also when I try to parse the Date object I get this error, "Use of unresolved identifier 'date'" 

Any idea why?

Comment: make sure you write `if let snapshot = snapshot { /...` that will unwrap it (i.e. checking it is not nil, so your App won't crash!

Comment: I implemented that, but then I got this error "Contextual type for closure argument list expects 2 arguments, which cannot be implicitly ignored"

Comment: Check your exact syntax.  I've amended my answer to show whole code after `.getDocuments {`

Comment: I get what your saying now it should be like this 

 func loadData() {
        db.collection("sourses").getDocuments() {
            snapshot, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                if let snapshot = snapshot {
                    for document in snapshot.documents {
                        
                        let data = document.data() ......

It works except I get the two errors 

"Use of unresolved identifier 'date'"

 and 

Use of unresolved identifier 'timeStamp'

Comment: yeah I've just amended that it should be `let date =`. and  `timeStamp: date`

Comment: and make sure your closure after .getDocuments is `.getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in` Not: `.getDocuments() { snapshot, error in`. - You might be able do it that way, but it's not how I do it.

Comment: Ok, I'm still getting the "Use of unresolved identifier 'date'" on both the       date = timestamp.dateValue()       as well as the line below it       let newSourse = (name:name, content:content, timeStamp: date)

Comment: also you're a champ for helping me out this much!

Comment: it should be `let date = timeStamp.dateValue()` ... sorry, I'm just writing this in the browser, not testing it :/

Comment: Ok that did work, but now on the self.soureArray.append line I get this error       "Cannot convert value of type '(name: String, content: String, timeStamp: Date)' to expected argument type 'Sourse'"

Comment: You need to add `Sourse(` before name: name

Comment: Now everything runs fine without any errors at all...but it shows a blank tableview controller ;(. Any idea?

Comment: try and print your snapshot to the console to see what if anything is coming back from Firestore

Comment: make sure your collection name is spelt correctly and case-sensitive, and the same for your fields.

Comment: I tried replacing "self.sourseArray.append(newSourse)" with  print("\(newSourse)")   and nothing showed up..... I then commented it all out and used  print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())") as it shows as an example in the firestore guide and it printed out the data.

Comment: checked case sensitivity it is lowercase "sourses" in firestore.

Comment: ok, immediately after `for document in snapshot.documents {` add `print(document.data())`

Comment: Yep that prints it all.

Comment: TimeStamp might be failing ... revert code as I've shown above

Comment: Tried the new code and on the "let new sourse =..." line I  got this error "Use of unresolved identifier 'timeStamp'"

Comment: timestamp should be timeStamp

Comment: Nice :) ... Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

rbaldwin talked me through it, his answer is correct, I'm just posting the full loaddata function for the record.

```
func loadData() {
    db.collection("sourses").getDocuments() { (snapshot, error) in

        if let error = error {

            print(error.localizedDescription)

        } else {

            if let snapshot = snapshot {

                for document in snapshot.documents {

                    let data = document.data()
                    let name = data["name"] as? String ?? ""
                    let content = data["content"] as? String ?? ""
                    let timeStamp = data["timeStamp"] as? Date ?? Date()
                    let newSourse = Sourse(name:name, content:content, timeStamp: timeStamp)
                    self.sourseArray.append(newSourse)
                }
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}
```