# How do I return TableView datasource values if I'm using Firebase/Firestore to query the returning value?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, tableview

I understand that Firestore is asynchronous. I'm just having some trouble returning values for the `cellForRowAt` and `numberOfRowsInSection` methods. It's not returning any cells/rows because the return is outside the closure, but I cannot place the return inside of the closure. How do I go about circumventing this issue?

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    //Return the count how many workouts exist for each date.
    var counter = 0

    Firestore.firestore().collection("/users/\(self.userIdRef)/Days/\(dayIdArray[section])/Workouts/").getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in
        if error == nil && querySnapshot != nil {
            counter = querySnapshot?.count ?? 0
        }
    }
    return counter
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: self.cellID, for: indexPath)

    Firestore.firestore().collection("/users/\(self.userIdRef)/Days/\(dayIdArray[indexPath.section])/Workouts/").getDocuments { (querySnapshot, err) in

        if let err = err
        {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)");
        }
        else
        {

            let firstValue = querySnapshot!.documents[indexPath.row]

            let myData = firstValue.data()
            let myDayRef = myData["workout"] as? String ?? ""
            cell.textLabel?.text = "\(myDayRef)"
            cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center
            cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
            cell.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
            cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor(red: 0.1333, green: 0.2863, blue: 0.4, alpha: 1.0)
            cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 20)
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Don't call APIs in TableView delegates.call API in viewDidLoad() or  viewDidAppear() and create data array.then use that data in tableview delegate methods.

Comment: Any tips on how I would go about querying those values? I know that I probably need to store the values in a dictionary, since I have multiple workouts documents for each day document?

Answer (score -1):

You should reload your `tableView` after filling the cells as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50193117/10810527). Something like this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: self.cellID, for: indexPath)

    Firestore.firestore().collection("/users/\(self.userIdRef)/Days/\(dayIdArray[indexPath.section])/Workouts/").getDocuments { (querySnapshot, err) in

        if let err = err {

            print("Error getting documents: \(err)");

        } else {

            let firstValue = querySnapshot!.documents[indexPath.row]
            let myData = firstValue.data()
            let myDayRef = myData["workout"] as? String ?? ""

            cell.textLabel?.text = "\(myDayRef)"
            cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center
            cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
            cell.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
            cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor(red: 0.1333, green: 0.2863, blue: 0.4, alpha: 1.0)
            cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 20)

            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

Notice the `tableView.reloadData()`.

Comment: It really doesn't make sense to start the fetch operation inside `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`. Normally, you'd want to fetch the data on `viewDidAppear`, and store off the results. Then, upon receiving the (new) results, you update the table view.

Comment: Agree, but that's not what OP is asking for.